# How do I use getIndices here with the for loop?

Tags: java, javafx

```
public void calculateTotal(){
    int wheelIndex = wheels.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    int deckIndex = decks.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    int truckIndex = trucks.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    int [] miscArray = misc.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices();
    int miscTotal = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < miscArray.length; i++){
        miscTotal += miscPrices[miscArray[i]];
    }
}
```

---

My problems lies at `int [] miscArray = misc.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices();`

It's telling me to change to ObservableList, but if I were to change to that I cannot access `i < miscArray.length` or `miscArray[i]` index. Can anyone help?

Comment: As mentioned in the given answer, that method returns an `ObservableList`. An `ObservableList` is a `List` which is part of the "Java Collections Framework"—the often better alternative to arrays. See [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

The method `selectionModel.getSelectedIndices()` returns an `ObservableList<Integer>` and not an array. So you have to use that List, or convert that list into an array.

To get the size of the List you can just use the `list.size()` method. To get an Element from the List you can use `list.get(index)`. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) are the complete java docs for `ObservableList`.

```
public void calculateTotal(){
    int wheelIndex = wheels.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    int deckIndex = decks.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    int truckIndex = trucks.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    ObservableList<Integer> miscList = misc.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices();
    int miscTotal = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < miscList.size(); i++){
        miscTotal += miscPrices[miscList.get(i)];
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use Java Streams:

```
int miscTotal = miscList.stream().mapToInt(i -> miscPrices[i]).sum();
```

If you want to transform the `ObervableList` to an array (I would not do that) you can use the `list.toArray()` method.

Comment: Note it'd be better to use `list.toArray(new Integer[0])` so the array is of type `Integer[]` rather than `Object[]`.

Comment: Yes that's right, but I just wanted to mention that method in general, because in my opinion this would not be a good practice.